# Working with HTML,CSS and Jquery Or Javascript in WP7

Tags: html, css, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile

I am presently started working with mobile development and would like to know which is the best way to work with `Html`,`css` and `jquery/Javascript` for `WP7`.

As I have seen couple of things on the web as [Phone Gap](http://phonegap.com/),[Jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) and [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/)

1.I have some of the problems actually this is not a problem but as PhoneGap gives a starter template with C# solution.

But I'm working on `VB.Net`.I'm unable to work with the `C# solution` as If I convert to VB.Net the entire `starter template` it is not working.

2.Just now I had a look at `Jquery mobile` there is no `specific documentation` mentioned how to use it with `emulator in WP7`.

Can anyone show me the links where I can start with the basics of Jquery mobile with WP7 emulator.

3.Do you think there is any other best way so that I Can work with jquery, html and css in WP7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like PhoneGap is your best option here. Right now, it's the best way to deploy an HTML-based application on Windows Phone. The main thing that PhoneGap gives you is a bridge to the phone's hardware (things like volume buttons, vibration, etc.). It also gives you an easy way to wrap up your application into a package that can be installed like a real native app.

By themselves, other frameworks like jQuery Mobile, Sencha Touch and Kendo UI don't provide hardware access or the ability to deploy the app natively. They are purely UI frameworks, meaning they provide the interface widgets you'll use to build your app but little else. Generally, with these frameworks, you need to host the app somewhere like a website and access it through the browser.

Assuming you're running a Windows machine, you could host the app locally for development using Internet Information Services (IIS). Here's a [guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323972) to setting up a site. Then you could open the emulator and go to `http://localhost` to interact with your app. That would work, but it would be clunky.

The ideal scenario is to use both jQuery Mobile (or another UI framework) and PhoneGap to create a nice-looking, natively installable app.

What I'd recommend is trying to get PhoneGap set up in a VB project. From what I've seen, this shouldn't be too difficult. There are probably some details to work out, but mainly it looks like you need to copy the `www` and `GapLib` folders over. Then right click on `References` and browse to the `GapLib` .dll. You'll also need to get the `MainPage.xaml` and `MainPage.vb` files set up, but they probably just host a web browser control, so this should be straightforward.

Migrating the pieces into a new project should work a lot better than trying to convert an existing project.

If you post specific issues that you run into during the setup, I'm sure you could get them answered quickly.

Comment: @Josh-Thanks for your detailed explanation.I am totally convinced with you.And yes I have started with my first Phone Gap App :)

Comment: Sounds good. :) You might want to check out the [PhoneGap course](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=phone-gap-intro&highlight=john-sonmez_phone-gap-m5-build*1,2,3,8,4!john-sonmez_phone-gap-m1-introduction*1,4!john-sonmez_phone-gap-m4-api!john-sonmez_phone-gap-m2-setup*2!john-sonmez_phone-gap-m3-mobile-ui#phone-gap-m5-build) at Pluralsight, which was created by a colleague of mine. It's a great introduction, and you can get a 200-minute free trial of Pluralsight. (I'm not affiliated in any way--just a good deal).